# how to overlay NSWindow on application in full screen mode

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

```
hello everyone, I'm making an application and I need to overlay an NSWindow with debug information on top of applications opened in full screen mode. How can i do this? Here is my code -
```

```
let contentRect = NSScreen.main!.frame
let overlayWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: contentRect,
                                         styleMask: [.borderless, .fullSizeContentView],
                                         backing: .buffered,
                                         defer: false
)
overlayWindow.level = .screenSaver
                
overlayWindow.collectionBehavior = [.canJoinAllSpaces, .fullScreenAuxiliary, .stationary]
                
let size = contentRect.width/3
                
overlayWindow.setFrame(
    CGRect(
        x: contentRect.midX - size/2,
        y: contentRect.midY - size/2,
        width: size,
        height: size
        ),
        display: true
    )
                
    overlayWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

![Значок "Проверено сообществом"](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAQAAAAngNWGAAAA/0lEQVR4AYXNMSiEcRyA4cfmGHQbCZIipkuxnJgMStlMNmeyD2dwmc8+sZgxYJd9ErIZFHUyYYD7fkr6l4/rnvmtl7+KitrqV/fq2Y5eLY3Z9S48eRLe7BmVZ9qhTLhQ0algzZWQOVKSsCF8OjAnwbxDTWFDUhPK/jMr1H6HE/IqRky2DyvCefuwItwZzodVoYRiLqMkVCXrwpJ9twZ+sgfDYEFYl8wIWxZ9uFf7zkallxlJh4YrLGsKjZRx7VGHhLqwgFUN45DGdb8MeXGpgB4ABZdeDcpZEY51A+hyLKz4S1W4MQWm3AibWtgWmk6dyISa1pSdyWTOlLXVp0+eL9D/ZPfBTNanAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)

```
i tried to add .stationary to collectionBehavior
```

![Значок "Проверено сообществом"](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAQAAAAngNWGAAAA/0lEQVR4AYXNMSiEcRyA4cfmGHQbCZIipkuxnJgMStlMNmeyD2dwmc8+sZgxYJd9ErIZFHUyYYD7fkr6l4/rnvmtl7+KitrqV/fq2Y5eLY3Z9S48eRLe7BmVZ9qhTLhQ0algzZWQOVKSsCF8OjAnwbxDTWFDUhPK/jMr1H6HE/IqRky2DyvCefuwItwZzodVoYRiLqMkVCXrwpJ9twZ+sgfDYEFYl8wIWxZ9uFf7zkallxlJh4YrLGsKjZRx7VGHhLqwgFUN45DGdb8MeXGpgB4ABZdeDcpZEY51A+hyLKz4S1W4MQWm3AibWtgWmk6dyISa1pSdyWTOlLXVp0+eL9D/ZPfBTNanAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)